# check if argument is not a list , then display message if it isnt a list

Tags: list, scheme

I have an argument called "evens" and all it does it get the even elements in a list, and it works fine with lists. But when passed in a atom like 'a, it crashes and says "*The object a, passed as the first argument to cdr, is not the correct type*. " now i don't want this function to handle atoms only list .

I have tried this but it seems to be wrong , this is kinda what im trying to do but still need some guidance.

```
    (IF  (NOT(LIST? lis)) "Enter valid list" ) => "Enter valid list" )
```

So how can i check if something that is not a list is being passed in. And if it is how do i display some kind of text message if it isn't a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, try this:

```
(if (not (list? lis))
    (display "Enter a valid list")
    ; else do the normal stuff here
    )
```

You should do the above verification before calling the actual function that you intend to implement.